# Guardar fecha en cassandra con spring

Tags: spring, date, cassandra

Estoy tratando de guardar la fecha de forma automática en cassandra atreves de spring, para lo cual cambio el tipo de fecha que obtengo con spring (Date) al formato de Cassandra (Date yyyy-mm-dd)

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<Cliente> crearCliente(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) {
    Date fecha = new Date();
    System.out.println(fecha);
    long lnMilisegundos = fecha.getTime();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(lnMilisegundos);

    cliente.setCreateAt(sqlDate);
    cliente.setUpdateAt(sqlDate);

    return clienteSevicio.crearCliente(cliente);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Cliente> crearCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    try {
        System.out.println(((Object)cliente.getCreateAt()).getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(cliente.getCreateAt());
        Cliente _cliente = clienteRepositorio.save(new Cliente(UUIDs.timeBased(), cliente.getNombre(), cliente.getApellido(), cliente.getEmail(), cliente.getCreateAt(), cliente.getUpdateAt()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(_cliente, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }catch (Exception e ) {
        System.out.printf("Error");
        System.out.println(e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Estoy imprimiendo por consola el tipo de dato y el dato (la fecha) para ver si están bien e imprime lo siguiente:
Date
2020-10-02

Pero también me esta imprimiendo el error el cual es:

```
Errororg.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: SessionCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO clientes (apellido,create_at,email,id,nombre,update_at) VALUES ('string',1601646868204,'string3',c9ee78e0-04b6-11eb-bfa7-39627886e1eb,'string2',1601646868204);]; Expected 4 byte long for date (8); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 4 byte long for date (8)
```

Viendo el error, me esta pasando como fecha "1601646868204" cuando debería ser "2020-10-02", por que esta sucediendo esto? que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione Cambiando el tipo de dato de fecha que tenia. Cambie de Date a LocalDate, por que con date estaba pasando el dato en milisegundos y así convirtiera la fecha a string con el formato correcto y luego lo pasara a Date de nuevo, me enviaba la fecha en milisegundos.

```
LocalDate fecha = new LocalDate.now();
```